# Cast uint64_t to FILETIME

Tags: c, time, endianness, filetime

I'm trying to get byte array from file, interpret it like `uint64_t` and then cast this uint to `FILETIME`

After googling around and debugging a bit I've stuck at following wrong working code.

```
uint64_t win_filetime = *(uint64_t*)(&(((char*)buf)[(int)FILETIME_OFFSET]));
//at this moment win_filetime = 0x01cb3f90e7b52500
```

where `buf` contains needed bytes at `FILETIME_OFFSET`

Then trying to cast `t1 = *(FILETIME *)(&win_filetime);` or

```
t1.dwLowDateTime = (DWORD)win_filetime;
t1.dwHighDateTime = (DWORD)(win_filetime >> 32);
```

to pass it to the function

```
tm FILETIME_to_time_t(const FILETIME *lpFileTime) {

  time_t result;

  SYSTEMTIME st;

  struct tm tmp;

  FileTimeToSystemTime(lpFileTime,&st);

  memset(&tmp,0,sizeof(struct tm));

  tmp.tm_mday = st.wDay;
  tmp.tm_mon  = st.wMonth - 1;
  tmp.tm_year = st.wYear - 1900;

  tmp.tm_sec  = st.wSecond;
  tmp.tm_min  = st.wMinute;
  tmp.tm_hour = st.wHour;

  return tmp;
}
```

Function `FILETIME_to_time_t()` returns rubbish(i.e. year = 110)

Sample value from file: `0025B5E7903FCB0100` that [HexWorkshop](http://www.hexworkshop.com/) correctly parsing as 11:23:10 19.08.2010

Maybe there is lack of endianness conversion or another thing that I'm unable to spot now?

Comment: Are you sure year=110 isn't just 2010 after you subtract 1900 in your code?

Comment: Yep, nice catch. I've replaced this with direct `record->filetime->tm_year = record->filetime->tm_year - 1900;` before strftime. Many thanks for help.

Comment: You're welcome--I reformulated the comment as an answer in case that solved your problem so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your code is OK, it's just that the year shows 110 because you subtract 1900 in your code when populating the `struct tm`.  That's standard though--`struct tm` is *supposed* to contain the year minus 1900.  You just need to be careful when printing the value.